# Post image as stream using Facebook share dialog UI

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Can we post image as stream using Facebook share dialog. Currently it allows only to share image as link but i want it to be preview Facebook instead of redirect to the link URL once share on Facebook. I have allowed the extended permission(publish_action, user_photo) but still it share as a link.

Is there any way to publish the images as stream using in build Facebook share dialog without using Facebook API object.?

Quick help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The Feed dialog still allows to specify the thumbnail URL at runtime.

Comment: CBroe,
Thanks for the reply. With feed dialog it still share thumb as a link. I want posted images to be preview on my facebook wall instead of redirect to image link,

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.